# openssl_private_encrypt and "error:0E06D06C...NCONF_get_string:no value"

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I can generate all keys fine, when I go to encrypt the file I get an error thrown at me: `error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value` but googling and checking stackoverflow only shows people with problems generating the keys.
My code: [Here](http://pastebin.com/MHit3LkR)

EDIT: The error pops up when I put `or die(openssl_error_string());` after `openssl_private_encrypt($fileToEnc, $encFile, $privateKey)` but I am now getting `fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\xr1\encrypt.php on line 9`

Comment: Please provide the relevant code. Please be sure to specify where the problem occurs, and the exact error message.

Comment: Whenever i did the tabs messed up the formatting ^^^

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my fopen dir somehow and it just broke. It is all good and fixed now, thanks.